# Mximum hours spent by an employee on each project

Tags: mysql

[image: Screenshot]

I have this query

```
SELECT t.pname,MAX(t.name) ,MAX(t.total)
FROM 

(
SELECT  p.`id`,e.`name`,p.`pname`,(m.`hour`) AS total 
FROM employee e INNER JOIN epmap m ON m.`employeeID`=e.`id` INNER JOIN project p ON p.`id`=m.`projectID`

)t
GROUP BY t.id
```

it gives the right answer, but its not the good approach beacuse `Max(t.name)` not appropriate

Comment: please show sample data you have and expected result you want and also  tag the relevant dbms like sqlserver,oracle

Comment: @TheGameiswar i am doing in sql server and i add the picture of my query and result

Comment: If your dbms can use windows function, try to use `rank` or `row_number` (https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/)

Comment: Could you explain how _`Max(t.name)` is not appropriated_?

Comment: Use `sum()` for calculating total hours in sub-query?

Comment: @Rohit Kumar i use sum() in subquery but it didnot give accurate answer
SELECT t.pname.t.name,MAX(t.total)
FROM 
(SELECT  p.`id`,e.`name`,p.`pname`,SUM(m.`hour`) AS total 
FROM employee e INNER JOIN epmap m ON m.`employeeID`=e.`id` INNER JOIN project p ON p.`id`=m.`projectID`

GROUP BY e.`id` , p.`id`

)t
GROUP BY t.id

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result you need:

```
SELECT t.pname, t.name, t.hour as total
FROM (
  SELECT  p.id, e.name, p.pname, m.total,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by p.id order by m.hour desc) rn
  FROM employee e 
  INNER JOIN epmap m ON m.employeeID=e.id 
  INNER JOIN project p ON p.id=m.projectID
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` is not mysql, but SQL-SERVER

Comment: @Nebi If you check the edit history, you'll see that original tag was "sql server". Not my fault that the OP changed his mind about the product, is it?

Comment: that is true. Seems like OP needs to make up his mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT would probably let you get rid of the MAX on name.